# Meteor Password Protect complete Application

Tags: meteor, password-protection

Can I "Password-Protect" my whole Meteor Application something like "htaccess" in PHP?

For example: I don't want the public to have access to my site, but the client wants to see it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Didn´t recognize that this is the answer. First Google hit.
https://github.com/Jabbslad/basic-auth

**EDIT:**

In fact very Simple.

Add the package.

```
meteor add jabbslad:basic-auth
```

add this code in serverside code

```
var basicAuth = new HttpBasicAuth("guest", "password");
basicAuth.protect();
```

There are some more options you can see in the repository readme.md